# Simulating RAM in modelsim - cannot find library

Tags: intel-fpga, quartus-ii, modelsim

I have a design in Quartus that includes an (on chip) RAM module that was created using the altera mega wizard. The wizard warns me that to simulate i need to include the `altera_mf` file.

When I load my design in Modelsim and try to simulate, it errors out with "cannot instantiate `altsyncram`. Module not found.

Below my work library is a library called `altera_mf` which includes the `altsyncram` module in there. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to make Modelsim use it.

How do I add/link the `altera_mf` library to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link to the library.

Assuming it is mapped (i.e. you see `altera_mf` as a library as you say), this is just a case of adding a switch to your `vsim` command:

```
vsim  <options> -L altera_mf  <toplevel>
```

Replacing `<options>` with any existing options you have, and `<toplevel>` is the name of the top level module (which you should already have in your command).

---

If that doesn't work, you will also need to make sure the library is mapped:

```
vmap altera_mf ./path/to/your/libraries/altera_mf
```

Comment: thx that worked.